# Passing a date from query to a column header

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, pivot, dynamic-sql

I am working on a COVID database and I want to use part of the date from the `Last_Update` column of an import file, and use that as an alias for a column in that same file.

Here is an example of the import file:

```
    FIPS    County      Province_State  Country_Region  Last_Update            Lat          Long    Confirmed   Deaths  Recovered   Active
    45001   Abbeville   South Carolina   US             2020-05-30 02:32:48.00 34.22333378-82.46170658  39      0       0           39
    22001   Acadia      Louisiana        US             2020-05-30 02:32:48.00 30.2950649 -92.41419698  401     23      0           378
    51001   Accomack    Virginia         US             2020-05-30 02:32:48.00 37.76707161-75.63234615  7       12      0           815
```

Here is the expected result:

```
    Province_State  Country_Region  05-30
    --------------------------------------
    Abruzzo         Italy           3237
    Acre            Brazil          5841
    Aguascalientes  Mexico           797
    Aichi           Japan            506
```

The `Last_Update` date column imports as 2020-05-30 02:32:48.0000000 and I have used the following code to extract the shortened date format for the new column header to read 05-30

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR (MAX)

SET @ColumnName = (SELECT TOP 1[Last_Update] FROM [DailyImport5.30.20])
SET @Date =  SUBSTRING (@ColumnName,6,6)
PRINT @Date
```

Next I have tried to pass the variable of `@Date` to the new column header with no luck so far:

```
DECLARE @ColumnA nvarchar(max),
        @ColumnB nvarchar(max),
        @ColumnC nvarchar(max),
        @ColumnName VARCHAR (50),
        @Date VARCHAR (50),
        @table nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @table = 'DailyImport5.30.20'
SET @ColumnName ='(SELECT TOP 1[Last_Update] FROM [COVIDResearch].[dbo].[DailyImport5.30.20])'
SET @Date = 'SUBSTRING (@ColumnName,6,6)'

SELECT  
    @ColumnA = N'Province_State',
    @ColumnB = N'Salary',
    @ColumnC = N'@Date',
    @table = N'[COVIDResearch].[dbo].[DailyImport5.30.20]'

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ' +(@ColumnA)+','+(@ColumnB)+','+(@ColumnC)+ ' FROM '+(@table) +';'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Date".

I have also tried `PIVOT` but not been able to find how to read the date, trim it down, and then perform a pivot for all the results in the table. Not just a specified set of results.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good day, Something is not clear... how can you get data in the expected result which is not exists in the source data?!? How did you got Country Regions for example?!? Do you need to find the data from the Latitude and Longitude ? please explain the logic which should be used to get the expected result from the sample data

Comment: I download the raw file that Johns Hopkins University uses for their COVID map. They have done some of the heavy lifting in getting the data together and the import file is a representation of what they provide. The raw data is available here: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-28-2020.csv - Thank you so much for your reply!

Comment: Please do your part. We do not discuss the Corona here but transact SQL queries. I do not care where the come. What we need is a table with some data and you expected result according to sample data. Therefore, Please provide queries to create the sample the sample table and to insert some sample data. According to your sample table and sample data, please explain what is the expected result (you do have to use all the source data for the discussion. select 4 countries for example)

Comment: Your tutorial has some great info on how I can improve an import process. Thank you for your advice and helping me to think about how to clarify my posts in the future!

Comment: Well, I am not sure to who you referring @Pegghawk. If you speak about my comment then it seems like someone removed it. I really hate stackoverflow system from any aspect of it. I prefer the MSDN forums for example. Instead of focusing on helping people the system and community here focus on building a Q&A archive (which is legit goal but not my preferred) . Not to mentioned poor interface which does not allow to have a discussion (actually related to the first point and the goal of the system). Anyhow, if you spoke about my post, then thanks. I am sorry the rest will not be able to get it.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your needs 

Answer (score 1):

Alex gave me the final push to solve this issue. Here is my final code to extract the date from the import file, shorten it to just the month and day, then insert it as the column header for use in a new table.

```
    DECLARE @ColumnA nvarchar(max),
    @ColumnB nvarchar(max),
    @ColumnC nvarchar(max),
    @ColumnName VARCHAR (50),
    @Date VARCHAR (50),
    @table nvarchar(max),
    @sql nvarchar(max)
    SET @table = 'DailyImport5.30.20'
    SET @ColumnName =(SELECT TOP 1[Last_Update] FROM [COVIDResearch].[dbo].[DailyImport5.30.20])
    SET @Date = SUBSTRING (@ColumnName,6,6)
    SELECT  @ColumnA = N'Province_State',
            @ColumnB = N'Country_Region',
            @ColumnC = 'Confirmed AS [' + @Date + ']',
            @table = N'[COVIDResearch].[dbo].[DailyImport5.30.20]'

    SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ' +(@ColumnA)+','+(@ColumnB)+','+(@ColumnC)+ ' FROM '+(@table) +';'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you "print" your query (via `PRINT @sql`) and copy the text to a new query window you will find that it has a syntax error near `@Date` column name. Variable names are not allowed as column names.

You need to give an alias to an existing data column. What you want to do is something along these lines:

```
.... Omitted for brevity
SELECT  
    @ColumnA = N'Province_State',
    @ColumnB = N'Salary',
    -- You need to give an alias to an existing column in [DailyImport5.30.20] table
    -- Note: square brackets to avoid invalid identifiers, i.e. you assign value of @Date to @ColumnC.
    @ColumnC = 'Confirmed AS [' + @Date + ']', 
    @table = N'[COVIDResearch].[dbo].[DailyImport5.30.20]'

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ' +(@ColumnA)+','+(@ColumnB)+','+(@ColumnC)+ ' FROM '+(@table) +';'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Oh thank you Alex, that worked! I found a couple of other errors in my code, but here is the final code that produced the desired result: